# How to get html tags from string using regex for javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to make highlighting (colored) code possible for my online HTML & CSS editor.
Suppose I have a string like this one in javascript -

`"<h1>hello world!</h1> <br>  <span>Some text...</span>"`

How can I possibly extract all the html tags from this string using regex ?

The result should contain every html tag in the string for example -  `<h1>`,`</h1>`,`<br>`,`<span>`,`</span>`

The result can be in any format but it must contain every html tag in the string.

Comment: Recommended to use editor like [monaco-editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/index.html) or [codemirror](https://codemirror.net/) instead of doing from scratch

Comment: Thinking about parsing HTML with regexp?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/535480

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following regex to identify html tags from string,

```
(<([^>]+)>)
```

```js
const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
const str = "<h1>hello world!</h1> <br>  <span>Some text...</span>"

while ((result = regex.exec(str))) {
    if (result.index === regex.lastIndex) {
     regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(result[0])
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!